# Parsing large xlsx file, Date format case

Tags: java, date, apache-poi, xlsx

Because xlsx file may contain million rows, I decided to use poi event model, took example from [here](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/how-to.html)(ExampleEventUserModel), but found some problem parsing Date format cells.

For example I have in excel date 01.10.2011 in cell A15, but xml has:

```
<c r="A15" s="11"><v>40817</v></c>
```

It is not in date format, even not in millis for example.

How to parse date for event model?

Best regards.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Excel stores dates as a floating point number of days (and fractions of day) from a fixed starting point.  The value `40817` is the number of days from that starting point to 1 October 2011.

POI's `HSSFCell` has a `getDateCellValue()` method that returns a Java `Date`, and will do what you want.

Comment: Thanks, additionally, how to get that this cell is Date format, it doesn't have "t" attribute, or s="11" means it is Date?

Comment: The `s=` attribute is a style reference.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3154646

Answer (score 3):

In relation to your follow-up question about how to determine if the cell contains a date value or not the answer is that there isn't any easy way.

The cell, `<c>`, element has a type attribute `t` but it isn't used for this Excel serial date type. As such the only thing that distinguishes a cell that contains a date encoded as 40817 and a cell with the value 40817 is the format that is applied to the number (that is referenced via the `s` cell attibute).

In order to determine that format you would have to look up the `numFmtId` attribute of the referenced style `xf` in the associated `styles.xml` and try to determine if that format is a date format. And in order to do that you would have to apply some heuristics.

All in all this is a huge pain when you wish to differentiate dates from other numeric data and to me this is an oversight in the SpreadsheetML format.

P.S. The OOXML standard does define a `d` date value for the `t` type attribute but that is only used for ISO 8601 dates which aren't actually produced by Excel. (Update: this date format is now used in Excel 2013 in strict mode).